# How to disable eslint overlay in latest Vue?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, eslint, vue-cli, eslintrc

I used to have this in `vue.config.js` but it no longer works after latest upgrade of vue or its deps:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
  // disable eslint nag screen when building for different environments
  if (!isProduction) config.module.rules.delete('eslint');
}
```

There is a part of the docs of `vue-cli` that says I can do this:

```
  devServer: {
    overlay: {
      warnings: false,
      errors: false
    },
```

But it says `overlay` is not a valid option

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vue CLI 5 uses Webpack 5, which has moved `devServer.overlay` to [`devServer.client.overlay`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#overlay):

```js
// vue.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  devServer: {
    client: {
      overlay: {
        warnings: false,
        errors: false,
      },

      // or
      overlay: false,
    }
  }
})
```