# How to disable eslint errors showing in the browser

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app, eslint-config-airbnb

When I run my create react app application using npm start, the eslint errors are shown in the browser on top of my site. I expect to see these warnings and errors in the terminal but not in the actual website, how can I remove this?

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try searching for ESLint in the docs -> https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can disable errors in browser by adding the environment variable `ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS` as it is mentioned [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/).

If you have **.env** file in your project, just add this line to it, and re-build the app:

```
ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true
```

Comment: Good, thanks for the documentation link.

Answer (score 5):

Inside eslint.rc you will have section for your env within module.exports
you can add false to the browser parameter, this will also fix this issue

```js
env: {
    browser: false,
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using webpack devserver, this config works:

```
  devServer: {
    client: {
      overlay: false,
    },
    //your other config
  },
```

you can find more details here

https://webpack.docschina.org/configuration/dev-server/#overlay

Answer (score 1):

If you use custom webpack. (Not CRA)
Then you need to disable 'overlay' in webpack devServer.

[How can I disable the overlay for warnings in a React app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71051797/how-can-i-disable-the-overlay-for-warnings-in-a-react-app)