# React className property exceeds the maximum line length of 120

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this element:

```
<div className={`my_container ${theme} ${isSpanishLanguage && 'spanishLanguage'} ${isEnglishLanguage && 'englishLanguage'}`}></div>
```

And I ge the error that my line is too long. How can I split this line into multiple lines to avoid getting this error ?

Comment: Use prettier...

Comment: It's not an error. It's a warning from eslint. [You can adjust the rule for that in your `.eslintrc` file](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/max-len). No need to add prettier.

Comment: @Andy it is showed as an error in the console, with red color.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71747605/how-to-disable-eslint-errors-showing-in-the-browser @paulalexandru

Answer (score 1):

You could just rewrite that line like this:

```
<div
  className={`my_container ${theme} ${isSpanishLanguage && "spanishLanguage"}
${isEnglishLanguage && "englishLanguage"}`}
></div>;
```

However you shouldn't be doing this manually, you should be relying on a tool like `prettier` to do this for you automatically upon saving your work.

Or if you could just disable the `eslint` rule that complains about the length of your code line.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function like:

```js
function getClassName(isSpanishLanguage, isEnglishLanguage) {
  const classes = ['my_container'];
  if (isSpanishLanguage) {
    classes.push('spanishLanguage');
  }
  if (isEnglishLanguage) {
    classes.push('englishLanguage');
  }
  return classes.join(' ');
}
```

And call it with the appropriate params (even outside of jsx), or use a package like [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx).

Answer (score 0):

It is a lint error but I would like to suggest you one library for joining classes in your react app systematically.

I would suggest using https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames package. It allow you to join classes conditionally.

So the approach would be like

```
 <div className = {classNames(
                  [my_container] , [${theme}],
                  {[spanishLanguage]:isSpanishLanguage,
                    [englishLanguage]:isEnglishLanguage,
                  }
                 )
                }>
 </div>
```